# Connection pooling in JetEntityProviderFramework EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6, jet-ef-provider

Just noticed that https://github.com/bubibubi/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet supports connection pooling.  I am currently using https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider and would like to use connection pooling in the EF6 version until I have time to port the app to Core.

Can I setup connection pooling for JetEntityFrameworkProvider? If so, how?  Are there any things to watch for if I do turn on connection pooling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't. There is a connection pooling implementation in EF Core.
In that case there the ADO .Net provider for Access is implemented in a different project and there and has been projected since the beginning. That's not the case of EF 6 provider where the ADO .Net provider has been written step by step every time I found a Microsoft Access weird behaviour.

I don't know your case but I'm not using EF Core because of the missing lazy loading implementation. Reading the backlog I think that has been implemented some days ago.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data Seems to  talk about lazy loading.   That said.  I'm looking forward to using EntityFrameworkCore.  Is it stable for production yet?  Sorry about the late answer, we were out of office for a month on a business trip (using your software with over 40 tablets hitting a rest server using JetEntityFrameworkProvider!!!